# Web Application and Office365

Tags: java, asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, office365

I've a goal: write a web application (using ASP or Java, i don't care) that can add appointments to my office365 calendar.

Exist some way to do this?!

I've tryed to use EWS RESTfull Call with Java on Eclipse and with ASP/VB on Visual Studio (I've registered the app) but when i try to do the call i got always the error 401.

Just to tell you, if i try to do a RESTfull call like

```
https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts
```

in my chrome browes i got a good json response.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your token may not be correct. You can check it: https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/ValidatingYourToken.md

Here's a sample in .NET that creates events: http://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/1793